# Gtkmm 3.0 draw blinking shapes and use of timeouts

Tags: timeout, draw, gtkmm

In a Gtk::DrawingArea I have a pixbuf showing the layout of my house. I draw the measured room temperatures on it. I also would like to draw the state of my shutters on it with some lines. When and only when a shutter changes its state, I would love to make these lines blink with a time offset of 1 second. I assume, I would have to make use of a timeout triggered every second to redraw the lines for the shutters. I am already making use of a timeout every 2 minutes to fetch new data from the internet to be shown on my screen. I could set up the timeout to get called every second and then I would have to remember, when my last 2-minute fetch was accomplished, to trigger the next one on time. Also, if my shutters are not changing state like in 99.9 percent of their lifetime, I do not need blinking. It feels over engineered to me to call a method every second just to make a line blink. Is there a smarter way to do this?

I could post a lot of code here, but I think that would not help anybody understand my question. I am helpful for any hint.

Comment: Could you please clarify what you would like to accomplish? I am not sure I understand. You already have an event triggering a redraw every 2 minutes and you want another to happen ... every second but only when some state changes?

Comment: You could add minimal code (using `std::cout`s for example) to help understand.

Comment: @BobMorane Thanks for you asking for clarification. Yes you guess correctly. I already have the Glib::SignalTimeout functionality in use to trigger an event every two minutes resulting in a new draw. When a user wants to change a shutter a button needs to be clicked and then I would like to indicate that on the screen for the time it takes for moving the shutters by making some shapes blink. I now understand, that you can make use of many Glib::SignalTiemouts. A solution would be to instantiate aTimeout, when a shutter moves and delete it when done... I asume, there is no easier way than that.

Comment: Ok, I don't know of any better way.

Comment: Did you make it work?

Comment: I am on it. It will take a while, because my „home project“ has a lot more problems to be solved.  I post, in a couple of months when done.